# Limit custom migration to one model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have decided to implement registration option for my website, I used [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html) (signup with confirmation part). Following this material I have created Profile module to hold some info. Everything (seems to be) working now, but the problem is that old profiles throws `relatedObjectDoesNotExist` error. According to these two questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317816/relatedobjectdoesnotexist-user-has-no-userprofile), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640446/django-create-user-profile-for-existing-users-automatically)) I need to make a migration to create profiles for old user accounts. I tried to follow this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) as suggested in one of the answers, but then I try to run a migration I get following error: `KeyError: ('stv', 'bazinekaina')`

`stv` is the name of my app and `bazinekaina` is the name of the next model after the one I need to create profiles.

How to limit migration to only the first model?

My relevant `models.py` code:

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.get(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()

#next model, this one throws an error, despite the fact it should not be touched at all
class BazineKaina(models.Model):
    #bazines kainos modelis

    bazka = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    data = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.bazka)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bazinė kaina"
        get_latest_by = 'data'
```

Migration file crated after using `python manage.py makemigrations --empty stv` command, named `0001_initial.py`:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

def sukurti_profilius(apps, schema_editor):
    Profile = apps.get_model("stv", "Profile")
    for user in Profile.objects.all():
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

How and what I should fix to stop migrations from applying to the unrelated models (and throwing error)?

Sorry if it is basic question, but whole django is still very new to me.

Comment: if your old profile are throwing error, delete all previous users and delete all the migration files and redo the makemigrations and migrations command

Comment: That is the thing, I would like to avoid deleting old users by creating profiles for them.

Comment: try with get_or_create method in your model post save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your migration is named 0001_initial then it means that you don't have a migration that actually creates the table for the profile model.

Remove that migration and run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations stv
python manage.py makemigrations stv --empty --name create_profiles
```

Then you should have a file 0002_create_profiles.py and put the logic to create profiles there.

Comment: It turns out I messed my migration files, re-downloaded them from Git and tried your advise. Combined with some other tweaks to some other parts of my code for this moment I got everything working, hope I  will manage to move that out of development too.